# Accessing pixel information in CIE L* a*b* color space

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, rgb

I am using OpenCV for some of my image processing related codes. I am stuck at a particular point.

In a particular code, I need to compare the pixel values of an image based on it`s CIE L*a*b* values. I know for BGR we can do something like this :

```
// img is the image, suppose
uchar *data = ( uchar* )img->imageData;

for(i=0; i< img->height; i++)
    for(j=0; j<img->width; j++)
     {
         b = data[i*img->widthStep + j*img->nChannels + 0];
         g = data[i*img->widthStep + j*img->nChannels + 1];
         r = data[i*img->widthStep + j*img->nChannels + 2]; 
     }
```

My question is, can we do something similar for l*a*b* color model also ? I mean at first I convert the image by

```
cvCvtColor(img, lab, CV_BGR2Lab);
```

then accessing the individual channel info like in the above case (since L*a*b* is also made up of 3 channels, if am not wrong), can we get the pixel values ??

The reason I am asking this is I tried to implement it, but I`m getting some real weird values like very high negative numbers ( I used int datatype instead of uchar since I was unsure about the range 'a' and 'b' can have ) whereas in Wikipedia I saw that 'L' can have values only in the range of 0 to 100. So how exactly can I get those pixel values ??

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely, you can do that, why not? Be aware however, that output is somewhat specific (since `a` and `b` can be negative):

> ```
> On output 0≤L≤100, -127≤a≤127, -127≤b≤127
> The values are then converted to the destination data type:
>     8-bit images:
>         L <- L*255/100, a <- a + 128, b <- b + 128
> ```

note that `L` is also scaled to 0-255 range (instead of 0-100). See more [here](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bensapp/opencvdocs/ref/opencvref_cv.htm).

BTW how can you get negative numbers if your data type is *unsigned* char?

Comment: oops!! sorry, I forgot to mention that I used int data type since I was not sure about the range of values 'a' and 'b' can have. So...

But since you gave the specific ranges, it becomes much easier for me now to implement it. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: 16-bit is unsupported for this type of convertion in OpenCV (at least according to the link I provided), maybe that was the problem also?

Comment: The link that you provided, was really helpful. Now I could get what I wanted using few tweaks here and there. So I guess this one is sorted, until some new bugs again come up. Thanks man..!!

Next job is clustering, so I guess pretty soon am gonna post another question :P